# Hamiltonian path

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, graph

What I'm trying to implement is a [Hamiltonian path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) finder using [backtracking algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hamiltonian-cycle-backtracking-6).

> ***NOTE:*** *While most of math papers and SO topics I managed to find are either concerned with answering the question 'whether Hamiltonian
>   path/cycle' exists or dedicated to finding Hamiltonian **cycle**, my problem
>   is slightly different - I need to find out the sequence of vertexes,
>   Hamiltonian **path** passes through*

For a sample graph (unused edges are black, vertexes are indexed 0-based):
[image]

I have built up an adjacency matrix (vertexes are indexed 1-based) of the following representation:

```
const vertexes = [ { vertex: 1, peers: [ 3, 8, 15 ] },
  { vertex: 2, peers: [ 7, 14, 23 ] },
  { vertex: 3, peers: [ 1, 6, 13, 22 ] },
  { vertex: 4, peers: [ 5, 12, 21 ] },
  { vertex: 5, peers: [ 4, 11, 20 ] },
  { vertex: 6, peers: [ 3, 10, 19 ] },
  { vertex: 7, peers: [ 2, 9, 18 ] },
  { vertex: 8, peers: [ 1, 17 ] },
  { vertex: 9, peers: [ 7, 16 ] },
  { vertex: 10, peers: [ 6, 15 ] },
  { vertex: 11, peers: [ 5, 14 ] },
  { vertex: 12, peers: [ 4, 13 ] },
  { vertex: 13, peers: [ 3, 12, 23 ] },
  { vertex: 14, peers: [ 2, 11, 22 ] },
  { vertex: 15, peers: [ 1, 10, 21 ] },
  { vertex: 16, peers: [ 9, 20 ] },
  { vertex: 17, peers: [ 8, 19 ] },
  { vertex: 18, peers: [ 7 ] },
  { vertex: 19, peers: [ 6, 17 ] },
  { vertex: 20, peers: [ 5, 16 ] },
  { vertex: 21, peers: [ 4, 15 ] },
  { vertex: 22, peers: [ 3, 14 ] },
  { vertex: 23, peers: [ 2, 13 ] } ]
```

Next, starting from vertex 18 as a root and `paths` array, containing single path `[[18]]`, I attempt to mutate that array replacing it with its temporary copy that holds original routes (if not dead-ended) with one step forth until there's no potential routes or path of length `n` (total number of vertexes) is found:

```
while(paths.length>0){
    let tempPath = [];
    for(path of paths){
     const nextSteps = vertexes.find(({vertex}) => vertex == path[path.length-1]).peers.filter(v => !path.includes(v));
     if(!nextSteps.length) continue;
     else if(path.length == n-1) return [...path, nextSteps[0]];
     else nextSteps.forEach(step => tempPath.push([...path,step]));
    }
    paths = tempPath;
}
```

So, the problem is above code never exits the loop and no desired output (`[18, 7, 9, 16, 20, 5, 11, 14, 22, 3, 1, 8, 17, 19, 6, 10, 15, 21, 4, 12, 13, 23, 2]`) ever returned.

Your ideas as of why above code fails and how to get it fixed to return expected output, would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:** Thanks to @DavidSampson and @trincot pointing out my spelling error, I got my code working now:

```
while(paths.length>0){
    let tempPath = [];
    for(let path of paths){
     const nextSteps = vertexes.find(({vertex}) => vertex == path[path.length-1]).peers.filter(v => !path.includes(v));
     if(!nextSteps.length) continue;
     else if(path.length == n-1) return [...path, nextSteps[0]];
     else tempPath.push(...nextSteps.map(v => [...path,v]));
    }
    paths = tempPath;
}
```

And now performance is my major concern, are there any suggestions as to how to improve one?

Comment: `while(paths.length>0){` Nowhere in the while loop do you actually change the value of `paths`. Since it starts with one element in it (`[18]`), and you never change it, `paths.length > 0` will always be true, and so the loop will run forever.

Comment: To improve performance, you should really consider a different algorithm. I suggest the dynamic programming one. It works for Hamiltonian Path as well as Hamiltonian Cycle. See for example https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/337

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue is a spelling mistake, which could have been circumvented if you would have used strict mode:

Change:

```
path = tempPath;
```

to:

```
paths = tempPath;
```

Also declare your variables. Like here:

```
for (let path of paths) {
//   ^^^^
```

Then it works for me:

```js
"use strict";

function hamiltonian(vertexes, start) {
    let n = vertexes.length;
    let paths = [[start]];  
    while(paths.length>0) {
        let tempPath = [];
        for(let path of paths){
            const nextSteps = vertexes.find(({vertex}) => vertex == path[path.length-1]).peers.filter(v => !path.includes(v));
            if(!nextSteps.length) continue;
            else if(path.length == n-1) return [...path, nextSteps[0]];
            else nextSteps.forEach(step => tempPath.push([...path,step]));
        }
        paths = tempPath;
    }
}

const vertexes = [ { vertex: 1, peers: [ 3, 8, 15 ] },{ vertex: 2, peers: [ 7, 14, 23 ] },{ vertex: 3, peers: [ 1, 6, 13, 22 ] },{ vertex: 4, peers: [ 5, 12, 21 ] },{ vertex: 5, peers: [ 4, 11, 20 ] },{ vertex: 6, peers: [ 3, 10, 19 ] },{ vertex: 7, peers: [ 2, 9, 18 ] },{ vertex: 8, peers: [ 1, 17 ] },{ vertex: 9, peers: [ 7, 16 ] },{ vertex: 10, peers: [ 6, 15 ] },{ vertex: 11, peers: [ 5, 14 ] },{ vertex: 12, peers: [ 4, 13 ] },{ vertex: 13, peers: [ 3, 12, 23 ] }, { vertex: 14, peers: [ 2, 11, 22 ] },{ vertex: 15, peers: [ 1, 10, 21 ] },{ vertex: 16, peers: [ 9, 20 ] },{ vertex: 17, peers: [ 8, 19 ] },{ vertex: 18, peers: [ 7 ] },{ vertex: 19, peers: [ 6, 17 ] },{ vertex: 20, peers: [ 5, 16 ] },{ vertex: 21, peers: [ 4, 15 ] },{ vertex: 22, peers: [ 3, 14 ] },{ vertex: 23, peers: [ 2, 13 ] } ];

let result = hamiltonian(vertexes, 18);
console.log('result', result);
```

Note that with dynamic programming you could improve the running time. Check out the different approaches on [Hamiltonian path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem#Algorithms).

Comment: Having fixed the typo `path`->`paths`, I managed to get my code working too (with certain minor corrections). And now, *'running time'* is exactly the issue for me. Could you please, elaborate a bit *`with dynamic programming you could improve the running time`*? As backtracking algorithm is the only one I seem to be able to implement (comprehend) so far.

Comment: Dynamic programming (you can look it up) means you memoize earlier results. You still search like you do now, but you backtrack earlier when you are able to use the memoized information. The Wikipedia link explains exactly what needs to be memoized, and when to use that during the search. I would say: have a go at it, try to implement it, and if you bump into a *specific* question about that, submit that as a new question. Make sure it is specific and to provide your code that attempts to implement dynamic programming.